# sending parameters as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameter-passing

Could I push all of the local variables into a single array and  pass it from `ArrValues` to `doit1`  I'm trying to find a way to call and collect only the arrays I want.

```
a="doit1";

arr="all";
ArrValues(a,arr);

function ArrValues(a,arr){

  var func=a;
  var num=arr;
  var ID = num=='one' || num=='all' ? ['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4'] : [];
  var Nam = num=='two' || num=='all' ? ['dog','bike','horn','goat'] : [];
  var X = num=='three' || num=='all' ? ['696','258','601','204'] : [];
  var Y = num=='four' || num=='all' ? ['119','590','594','125'] : [];
  window[func](ID,Nam,X,Y);
 }
function doit1(ID,Nam,X,Y){
 alert(ID);
 alert(Nam);
 alert(X);
 alert(Y);
}
```

Comment: Single array and keeping their names? Names of what?

Comment: Never mind the name part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
var dict = { 'ID' : ID, 'Nam' : Nam, 'X' : X, 'Y' : Y };
```

And pass that one to your function. (*e.g.* `doIt(dict);` or `window[func](dict);`)

---

You may then easily access any of the objects variables like this :

```
function doIt(d)
{
    alert(d.ID);
    alert(d.Nam);
    alert(d.X);
    alert(d.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing an array, pass an object.

```
{
    ID: num=='one' || num=='all' ? ['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4'] : [],
    Nam: num=='two' || num=='all' ? ['dog','bike','horn','goat'] : [],
    X: num=='three' || num=='all' ? ['696','258','601','204'] : [],
    Y: num=='four' || num=='all' ? ['119','590','594','125'] : [],
}
```

Comment: What would be the difference in using an object vs a global array which is faster?  I was trying to maintain local scope. I need it to also execute as fast as possible.

Comment: A global array isn't faster! Arrays are a special type of object, but accessing members of arrays, objects and variables in global/local scope are all basically the same thing. You can change its scope by changing where you declare the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can stuff everything in an object and pass that object on to the next function. From the next function, you can access the values via that object.

```
function ArrValues(func, num) {

  var obj = {}
    , all = (num === 'all')
    ;

  obj.ID = (all || num === 'one') ? ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'] : [];
  obj.Nam = (all || num === 'two') ? ['dog', 'bike', 'horn', 'goat'] : [];
  obj.X = (all || num === 'three') ? ['696', '258', '601', '204'] : [];
  obj.Y = (all || num === 'four') ? ['119', '590', '594', '125'] : [];

  window[func](obj);
}

function doit1(obj) {
  alert(obj.ID);
  alert(obj.Nam);
  alert(obj.X);
  alert(obj.Y);
}

a = "doit1";
arr = "all";
ArrValues(a, arr);
```